# Prevent null forgiving operator usage

Tags: c#, nullable, static-analysis, editorconfig

As part of the work we do maintaining a project we typically end up discussing the null forgiving operator `!` in PR reviews and have been trying to explore ways to prevent it's use altogether.

I am ideally trying to find a way to prevent it's usage through `.editorconfig` and forcing it to be an error however I have struggled to find any clear options. Is this possible?

If it isn't are there any known other ways of enforcing this desired behaviour?

Comment: Can your source control can be configured to reject attempts to commit source with ! at the end of a word?

Comment: You could write an analyzer that detects it as a syntax node and have it produce an error. Reference the analyzer as a NuGet package (private source, if you want) or install it as an extension and require that all developers have it installed. The package has the benefit of not requiring developer configuration, but the drawback of having to remember to reference it in every project you create.

Comment: I opened a compiler/roslyn issue for this and it was rejected   https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/5934

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had started to write my own Roslyn Analyzer as suggested in comments until a friend pointed me at this repository which has already provided it:

https://github.com/tom-englert/Nullable.Extended

There is an extension or a NuGet Package option which looks exactly like we need.